# Independent and identically distribued random variables $X_i$ with $X_1 \sim \exp(1/2)$

Tags: probability

We note $S_n = x + \sum_{i=1}^n X_i$ where $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and $X_i$ are real-valued random variables (independent and identically distributed). We notice that $X_1$ follows an exponential distribution with parameter $1/2$.

I have to determine $\lim_{n \rightarrow +\infty} \mathbb{P}(S_n>0)$.

Thus, I wrote $\lim_{n \rightarrow +\infty} \mathbb{P}(S_n>0) = \lim_{n \rightarrow +\infty} \mathbb{P}(\sum_{i=1}^n X_i > -x)$.

I really don't know how to pursue. Could someone help me ?

Comment: Do you know that the sum of exponential distribution follow Gamma distribution?

Comment: Hint: Use the law of large numbers.

Comment: It won't matter for this problem, but is this parameter the mean, or the "rate"?

Comment: Thanks you. I will use the law of large numbers !

Comment: The limit is $\Large 1$.

Comment: "I will use the law of large numbers !" Did you? Then, to show what happened when you did would be more productive than to accept the rather bizarre answer below.

Comment: @Did: Here it may be better to use the maxim (more commonly applied to web cartoonists and story-tellers) *Show, don't tell!*  It won't be a waste of your time to put that wall of calculations to shame.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Thanks for inducing me into reading the [WP page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Show,_don%27t_tell), it is instructive (and it says the concept is often attributed to Chekhov...). Yes this is one of those cases where one really wonders what the OP was after when they came here, since they hurry to accept a mostly irrelevant answer despite being shown the way to the relevant notions. Thus, in case your suggestion would be that I post an answer myself, I am sorry to have to decline, since that would amount to force-feeding somebody who showed only lack of interest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> $\ds{S_{n} \equiv x + \sum_{i = 1}^{n}X_{i}}$.

\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}\bracks{S_{n} > 0} & \equiv
\int_{0}^{\infty}{1 \over 2}\expo{-x_{1}/2}\cdots
\int_{0}^{\infty}{1 \over 2}\expo{-x_{\large n}/2}
\bracks{x + \sum_{k = 1}^{n}x_{k} > 0}\dd x_{1}\ldots\dd x_{n}
\\[5mm] & =
{1 \over 2^{n}}\int_{0}^{\infty}\!\!\!\!\expo{-x_{\large n}/2}
\cdots
\int_{0}^{\infty}\!\!\!\!\expo{-x_{\large n}/2}
\braces{\int_{0^{+} - \infty\ic}^{0^{+} + \infty\ic}
{\expo{\pars{x + \sum_{k = 1}^{n}x_{k}}s} \over s}{\dd s \over 2\pi\ic}}
\dd x_{1}\ldots\dd x_{n}
\\[5mm] & =
{1 \over 2^{n}}\int_{0^{+} - \infty\ic}^{0^{+} + \infty\ic}{\expo{xs} \over s}
\pars{\int_{0}^{\infty}\expo{-\pars{1/2 - s}\xi}\dd\xi}^{n}
\,{\dd s \over 2\pi\ic} =
{1 \over 2^{n}}\int_{0^{+} - \infty\ic}^{0^{+} + \infty\ic}
{\expo{xs} \over s\pars{1/2 - s}^{n}}
\,{\dd s \over 2\pi\ic}
\\[5mm] & =
{\pars{-1}^{n} \over 2^{n}}\int_{0^{+} - \infty\ic}^{0^{+} + \infty\ic}
{\expo{xs} \over s\pars{s - 1/2}^{n}}
\,{\dd s \over 2\pi\ic}
\\[5mm] & =
{\pars{-1}^{n} \over 2^{n}}\braces{\!\!\!%
\bracks{x < 0}\expo{x/2}\!\!\!\!\int_{0^{+} - \infty\ic}^{0^{+} + \infty\ic}
\!\!\!{\expo{x\pars{s - 1/2}} \over s\pars{s - 1/2}^{n}}\,{\dd s \over 2\pi\ic} +
\bracks{x > 0}\!\!\int_{0^{+} - \infty\ic}^{0^{+} + \infty\ic}\!\!\!
{\expo{xs} \over s\pars{s - 1/2}^{n}}\,{\dd s \over 2\pi\ic}}
\\[5mm] & =
{\pars{-1}^{n} \over 2^{n}}\braces{%
\bracks{x < 0}\expo{x/2}\int_{0^{+} - \infty\ic}^{0^{+} + \infty\ic}
{\expo{x\pars{s - 1/2}} \over s\pars{s - 1/2}^{n}}\,{\dd s \over 2\pi\ic} +
\bracks{x > 0}\pars{-1}^{n}\, 2^{n}}
\end{align}
Note that
\begin{align}
\mrm{Res}\bracks{{\expo{x\pars{s - 1/2}} \over s\pars{s - 1/2}^{n}},
z = {1 \over 2}} & =
2\,\mrm{Res}\bracks{{\expo{x\pars{s - 1/2}} \over
\bracks{1 + 2\pars{s - 1/2}}\pars{s - 1/2}^{n}}, z = {1 \over 2}}
\\[5mm] & =
2\,\mrm{Res}\bracks{\sum_{i = 0}^{\infty}{x^{i}\pars{s - 1/2}^{i - n} \over i!}
\sum_{j = 0}^{\infty}\pars{-1}^{j}2^{j}
\pars{s - {1 \over 2}}^{j},z = {1 \over 2}}
\\[5mm] & =
2\,\mrm{Res}\bracks{\sum_{i = 0}^{\infty}\sum_{j = 0}^{\infty}
{x^{i}\pars{s - 1/2}^{i - n + j} \over i!}
\pars{-1}^{j}2^{j},z = {1 \over 2}}
\\[5mm] & =
2\sum_{i = 0}^{\infty}\sum_{j = 0}^{\infty}
{x^{i}\pars{-1}^{j}2^{j} \over i!}\,\bracks{i - n + j = -1}
\\[5mm] & =
2\sum_{i = 0}^{\infty}
{x^{i}\pars{-1}^{n - i - 1}2^{n - i - 1} \over i!}\,\bracks{n - i - 1 \geq 0}
\\[5mm] & =
2\pars{-1}^{n - 1}\,2^{n - 1}\sum_{i = 0}^{n - 1}
{\pars{-x/2}^{i} \over i!} =
\pars{-1}^{n - 1}\,2^{n}\,\mrm{e}_{n - 1}\pars{-\,{x \over 2}}
\end{align}

---

$$
\bbx{\mathbb{P}\bracks{S_{n} > 0} =
\bracks{x < 0}\expo{x/2}\mrm{e}_{n - 1}\pars{-\,{x \over 2}} + \bracks{x > 0}
\,,\qquad
\mrm{e}_{m}\pars{z} \equiv \sum_{k = 0}^{m}{z^{k} \over k!}}
$$
$$
\bbx{\lim_{n \to \infty}\mathbb{P}\bracks{S_{n} > 0} =
\bracks{x < 0}\expo{x/2}\expo{-x/2} + \bracks{x > 0} =
\color{red}{\large 1}}
$$

[image]